# Kept getting false for sheets that definitely DO exist

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I created a simple function to check if a sheet exists, but kept getting false for sheets that definitely DO exist.

[image]

So I changed it to list all the sheets using getSheets(), and not getting any results. I'm running the function 'test':

```
function test(){
  var rv = sheetExists("Summary");
  // var rv = sheetExists("Import");
  // Logger.log("rv: " + rv);
}
function sheetExists(sheetName){
  // var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets;

  if (sheets.length > 1) {
    Logger.log(sheets[1].getName());
  } else {
    Logger.log("No sheets !!!");
  }

  // // var rv = sheet ? true : false;
  // // var rv = (sheet != null);
  // // Logger.log("rv: " + rv);
  // if (sheet != null) {
  //   rv = true;
  //   Logger.log('rv: ' + rv + '; index: ' + sheet.getIndex());
  // } else {
  //   rv = false;
  //   Logger.log('rv: ' + rv);
  // }
  // return rv;
}
```

I can't see what I'm doing incorrectly?

Comment: add bares to getSheets Like this
var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();

Comment: You forgot brackets `()` after `.getSheets`

Comment: So I did, thanks guys!  Sometimes I just miss the obvious. :)

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, I forgot the brackets `()`.  Du-oh!